# Playing a video from a url

Tags: ios

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player;
    NSLog(@"%@",gotVideo);
    NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString:gotVideo];
    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:urlString];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];


    //---play movie---
    [player play];

}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];
}
```

In iOS 7.1 simulator the video is not getting played. Please provide any suggestions.

Comment: Tried it on a real device?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",gotVideo); - in this place u getting the url

Comment: As SergiusGee adviced try it on the devices. Those mobile emulators often have problems fetching online resources. Most significantly observable on the android emulator!

Comment: Yes it is a url@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: No i have not tried it on a real device. Is it not feasible to play it on a simulator

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to present it or add as subview

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:player];
//---play movie---
[player play];
```

Comment: Then check your url and follow some simple tutorial http://www.appcoda.com/video-recording-playback-ios-programming/

Answer (score 0):

**Try This code**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad]; 


 NSURL *urlString=[NSURL URLWithString: urlString];
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: urlString];  
                [player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(//set rect frame)];
                player.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleDefault; 
                player.shouldAutoplay=YES;
                player.repeatMode = NO;  
                [player setFullscreen:YES animated:NO]; 
                [player prepareToPlay];
                [player play];
    [self.view addsubview: player.view];

      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:player];

    }
    - (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
        MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         removeObserver:self
         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
         object:player];
    }
```

Comment: Not Working @Vibha Singh

Comment: I think you check URL..Problem is not with code may be it is due to URL.

Comment: URL is fine it is showing up on the browser respective video and hitting the same url m getting the thumbnail image for the button. Now clicking this should display the video. Video is not getting played instead a black screen with the frame is appearing

Comment: It will not work if same url doing two jobs at a time.It is confusing to player..Can u plz share URL so that I can check from my end or try any other video URL from youtube.

Comment: No url is sent to another view controller. i have checked this code with a url from youtube also not working on my side.